# How to Edit Rails Scaffold Model generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, scaffold

I am trying to customise rails default scaffold generators. For views I can do that by simply adding files under : `lib/templates/erb/scaffold/`

Here I have added index.html.erb and customized, but I want to change model that is generated by this command:

```
rails g scaffold model
```

I have tried adding files to  lib/templates/rails/model/model_generator.rb

with codes like this :

```
 module Rails
    module Generators
      class ModelGenerator < NamedBase #metagenerator
        argument :attributes, :type => :array, :default => [], :banner => "field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]"
        hook_for :orm, :required => true

      end
    end
  end
```

But it is doing nothing I need help in this regard  what file I need to override and where do I need to place.

Comment: What do u want to change within the model generated ?

Comment: need to add some values I want to put some custom validation inside model during rails g scaffold model  test:string I need to put this test thing inside model with my codes simple I need to find a way to edit model and controller if possible

Comment: how about manually creating a model file instead ?

Comment: I did  not get your point I need to automate just want to feed everything in scaffold and and it should do the magic I have many modules same thing so this will help me increase development speed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [Activerecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb.tt) template. You need to put it in `lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb` as

```
 ~/D/p/p/generator_test> tree lib/
lib/
├── assets
├── tasks
└── templates #<========
    └── active_record
        └── model
            └── model.rb
```

Here is my **custom template**

```
<% module_namespacing do -%>
class <%= class_name %> < <%= parent_class_name.classify %>

   #custom method start
   before_save :my_custom_method

   # my method
   def my_custom_method

   end
   #custom method end

<% attributes.select(&:reference?).each do |attribute| -%>
  belongs_to :<%= attribute.name %><%= ', polymorphic: true' if attribute.polymorphic? %><%= ', required: true' if attribute.required? %>
<% end -%>
<% attributes.select(&:token?).each do |attribute| -%>
  has_secure_token<% if attribute.name != "token" %> :<%= attribute.name %><% end %>
<% end -%>
<% if attributes.any?(&:password_digest?) -%>
  has_secure_password
<% end -%>
end
<% end -%>
```

**Running scaffold**

`rails g scaffold property`

**File created**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord

   before_save :my_custom_method

   # my method
   def my_custom_method

   end

end
```

Comment: awesome how to do the same with controller where and which file I need to put in lib folder

Answer (score 3):

To simplify, you can copy all the ActiveRecord model templates to your current Rails project with this command:

```
mkdir -p lib/templates/active_record/model && \
cp $(bundle info activerecord --path)/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/* lib/templates/active_record/model
```

Comment: Really will that work suppose if I have to change a generated route and I want to add something to resource

Comment: The code for scaffolding routes will be in the Railties gem - under `lib/rails/generators/rails/resource_route/resource_route_generator.rb`. You could copy it to `lib/templates/resource_route/` and customise it.

Comment: If its not updating, make sure to restart `spring` or use `DISABLE_SPRING=true rails g model ...`